# How to add headers in AFNetworking 4.0 in POST Request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am doing this for defining headers in AFNetworking 4.0

```
      NSMutableDictionary *headers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
      [headers setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[defaults valueForKey:@"Token"]]  forKey:@"Authorization"];
      [manager POST:[NSURL URLWithString:path].absoluteString parameters:parameter headers:headers progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
         { 

          }
```

And this is the method new POST method define in AFNetworking 4.0

```
    - (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:(NSString *)method
                                   URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                  parameters:(nullable id)parameters
                                     headers:(nullable NSDictionary <NSString *, NSString *> *)headers
                              uploadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress *uploadProgress)) uploadProgress
                            downloadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress *downloadProgress)) downloadProgress
                                     success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id _Nullable responseObject))success
                                     failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError *error))failure
     { 

      }
```

While doing This is showing me error "[<__NSDictionary0 0x10c62a870> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Authorization."

Please tell me correct solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Above Given Answers I found a midway for the answers. Thanks for the Response @baiyidjp and @Silversky Technology

```
     AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
     [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];

     NSString *path=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",URL];

     NSMutableDictionary *parameter = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [parameter setValue:@"123456" forKey:@"id"];

     NSDictionary *headers = @{@"Authorization":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[defaults valueForKey:@"ApiToken"]]};

      [manager POST:[NSURL URLWithString:path].absoluteString parameters:parameter headers:headers progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
         {
          NSLog(@"Response Object response is....==%@",responseObject);
          }
              failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)
         {
          NSLog(@"Error Last 2 Done: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am use AFN 4.0 now, but I add header also on manager like this:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *sessionManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];    
[sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:bearerToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

and GET/POST/PUT/DELETE header I send @{} to backend
```

I hope I can help you

Comment: I want to know Why you have added for GET/POST/PUT/DELETE header : @{} to backend ?? because this will clarify my doubt clearly.

Comment: Because I have uniformly loaded the header in sessionManager, When I want to add header to GET / POST separately, I don't pass @ {} to the backend

Answer (score 0):

Use this Block Method

```
+(void)postServiveCall:(NSDictionary *)perameters headers:(NSArray *)headers WithSuccess:(void (^)(id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)( NSError *error))failure
{

   AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

   if(headers.count > 0)
   {
    for (NSDictionary *headerData in headers)
    {
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:headerData.allValues.firstObject forHTTPHeaderField:headerData.allKeys.firstObject];
    }
   }
   AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
   responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];

   manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;

   NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@action.php",BASEURL];

   [manager POST:url parameters:perameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    success (responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    failure (error) ;

 }];
}
```

How to use this Give Below, Here you can Add multiple header field if you want

```
NSDictionary *postparam = @{@"action":@"versionCode",
                          @"version":version,@"device_type":@"iOS"
                          };

NSArray *heder = @[@{@"Authorization":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[defaults valueForKey:@"Token"]]}];

[ServiceCalls postServiveCall:postparam headers:heder WithSuccess:^(id responseObject)
 {
} failure:^(NSError *error)
{
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your answer need some corrections.So I have Found a solution with the help of both the given answer for the post.